# Should we reuse the cublasHandle_t across different calls?

Tags: cuda, cublas

I'm using the latest version CUDA 5.5 and the new CUBLAS has a stateful taste where every function needs a `cublasHandle_t` e.g.

```
  cublasHandle_t handle;
  cublasCreate_v2(&handle);
  cublasDgemm_v2(handle, A_trans, B_trans, m, n, k, &alpha, d_A, lda, d_B, ldb, &beta, d_C, ldc);
  cublasDestroy_v2(handle);
```

Is it a good practice to reuse this handle instance as much as possible like some sort of a `Session` or the performance impact would be so small that it makes more sense to lower code complexity by having short-living handle instances and therefore create/destroy it continuously?

Comment: Multiple cuBLAS handle creation/destruction can break concurrency by unneeded context synchronizations.

Comment: Also, from the cuBLAS Library User Guide, "`cublasCreate()` [...] allocates hardware resources on the host", so perhaps there is some overhead on its call.

Comment: It is worth also copying this from the documentation: _"Because cublasCreate allocates some internal resources and the release of those resources by calling cublasDestroy will implicitly call cublasDeviceSynchronize, it is recommended to minimize the number of cublasCreate/cublasDestroy occurences."_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is a good practice for two reasons:

1. From the cuBLAS Library User Guide, "cublasCreate() [...] allocates hardware resources on the host", which makes me think that there is some overhead on its call.
2. Multiple cuBLAS handle creation/destruction can break concurrency by unneeded context synchronizations.

Answer (score 1):

As the CUDA Toolkit states in [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-context)

The application must **initialize** the handle to the cuBLAS library context by calling the cublasCreate() function. Then, **the context is explicitly passed to every subsequent library function call**. Once the **application finishes** using the library, it must call the function cublasDestory() to **release the resources** associated with the cuBLAS library context.